# Include external PHP script into Shopify store via webhook

Tags: php, shopify, webhooks

I am currently working on a Shopify store. I have a PHP script hosted on another server that I need to display on my shopify store.

The script I am using has to be included into a page via PHP.

This has to go in the header:

```
<?php require 'doo_inc/class/dooMCForm.php';?>
```

And this goes within the body where you wish to display the button:

```
<?php  echo $DooForm->doo_load_form(true, true, true,'blueBtn', Click here to Subscribe); ?>
```

I understand I should use webhooks to display the PHP on the website but I really am struggling with this...

I need to have the modal box loading onload rather than by a button aswell...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't include a PHP script within a Shopify template. Shopify templates allow only HTML, CSS, JavaScript and Liquid. HTML gives you a few possibilities to include external resources, for example an `iframe` or an external `script` (JavaScript). Using JavaScript you could also load an external resource and replace some of your HTML dynamically.

Webhooks can't be used to accomplish this task. Webhooks are used in back-end to back-end communication. You're developing something to be used in the front-end.